# How To Remove TouchScreen Hardware

Tags: touchscreen

Is there a way to physically remove touchscreen hardware and just have the monitor work as a normal display?

I have tried looking inside the computer for comments that may be responsible for handling the touchscreen specific components, however I still had no luck.

I have a feeling that maybe the components that I'm looking for are inside the screen enclosure itself...

Thanks

Comment: No; there is not

Comment: Thanks for replying Ramhound. Btw, the reason why I was asking is that the touchscreen is physically damaged and I can't control the computer without the touchscreen interfering, especially during a new installation of Windows.

Comment: Just use a mouse and ignore the touchscreen. Nowadays they are integrated into the glass of the screen and there is no way to remove them.

Comment: Hi Tom, the touchscreen is interfering even with the mouse connected. However, I found the cables that are responsible for the touch specific functionality, now I've just got to remove the screen from the bessel.

Comment: what os? why not disable the touchscreen in software?

Comment: Hi Gogoud. Because my OS was malfunctioning. (Blue Screen Of Death)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just removed the touchscreen ribbon cables instead of trying to disable it.

Thanks to everyone who have replied to this post.